# Passing huge datatable to a stored procedure for bulk insert OR inserting one record at a time

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, datatable

I need to process records from a table and need to log the outcome of processing of each record. One can pass a datatable to a stored procedure instead to insert all of them by using ADO.NET SqlDbType.Structured (more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S)). I need to build that datatable and then pass to the stored procedure. Would this approach still optimal with more that 12k rows (for the datatable) inside a Windows service? I am afraid this might consume too much memory on the server?
Not sure If I can build the datatable in batches and pass them to the stored procedure in this scenario.

**EDIT** :- In those 12K rows, there are no huge blobs on each row. It would be guid (Id), string (status) and string(ErrorMessage, If any) on each row.

Any advice or suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: The number of rows is not is important as the size of data. Having 1 mb blob in each row is different to having a bunch of ints.

Comment: BULK INSERT is probably faster than both, but if you have to choose between a TVP and inserting 12000 rows individually, I would absolutely 100% choose TVP.

Comment: @AaronBertrand wouldn't it matter if column 1 is of type varbinary(max) containing avg of 2MB of data per row?

Comment: @Pencho maybe, but why are you inventing a problem the OP hasn't stated?

Comment: @AaronBertrand He has. If the size of each row is too large then he will definitely run into the "...consume too much memory..." problem.

Comment: @Pencho the only number I see in the question is 12k, referring to the number of rows. Instead of attacking the question and other comments, why don't you let the OP tell us if they have MBs of data in each column, instead of assuming that must be the case? Anyway what is your magic answer if there are huge blobs in every row? You've stated it matters but have offered absolutely zilch regarding what to do about it. Instead you want to argue with me about how much data is in each column... everyone's definition of "huge" is different... <sigh>

Comment: @AaronBertrand and I have said that this number (12k) does not give enough information in order to choose an approach. Attacking comments?  I feel more like defending myself since the start of this.

Comment: @Pencho Maybe attacking was strong, but yeah we got your point the first time. Instead of dragging it out and pointing out the flaws in my suggestion let's wait for more info from the OP m'kay?

Comment: There are no huge blobs on each row. It would be guid (Id), string (status) and string(ErrorMessage, If any) on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table-Valued Parameters should be fine for 12K rows, even if the occasional status / error message values are longer.

Of course, you could always try it, since there are a lot of variables that may impact whether performance is acceptable, and we can't possibly account for all these variables that are specific to your environment, the application, and any extraneous apps or processes.